# duplicity exclude directories while restoring

Tags: duplicity, duply

How can I restore some files from my duplicity backup excluding some directories/files ?

Does --include --exclude work along with restore ?

Answer (score 1):

Vikas,

unfortunately not. in/exclude are not implemented in duplicity restore. you can however use `--file-to-restore` eg.

```
duplicity restore [--file-to-restore <relpath>] [--time <time>] <url> <target_folder>
```

as described in the man page [1] to restore a specific file/folder(recursively) only.

..ede/duply.net

[1] http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html